# How to find the characteristic equation of the following coupled time delayed system?

Tags: characteristic-polynomial, delay-differential-equations

Please suggest the how to find out the characteristic equation of the following system

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add what you already know and what you have tried.

Comment: can I use x1=x2=e^lamda*t